# git diff in my mvim

Tags: vim

I was used to doing

```
git diff | mate
```

but my new machine does not have mate and I use mvim. So I tried

```
git diff | mvim
```

and that did not work. What is the best way to see git diff in mvim editor.

I am using mac and I use mvim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know about mvim specifically, but with normal vim you have to give it a filename of - to make it read stdin:

```
git diff | vim -
```

Perhaps mvim works the same?

Comment: `git diff | vim -R -` to open vim read only so that you can just quit with `:q` and not need `:q!`!

Answer (score 5):

I do believe you might be seeking [this](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/git-diff-with-vimdiff/)... (obviously, with `mvimdiff` instead of `vimdiff`)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
mvim -d file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Running `git diff` and piping the results to an editor (as the questioner asked) is different than using `mvim` to diff two files (as you suggest). I see you are a new SO user. Thanks for posting, though!